# .NET MVC Strongly typed helper - Get value from property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-expressions, strongly-typed-helper

I'm creating a strongly typed helper (ref: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122424/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-strongly-typed-html-helper)). As 'commented' in the code below, **is it possible to somehow get the value from the expressed property and thus bypass the optional `selectedValue` parameter?**

```
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function DatePickerFor(Of TModel As Class, TProperty)(ByVal htmlHelper As HtmlHelper(Of TModel), ByVal expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty)), Optional ByVal selectedValue As Nullable(Of Date) = Nothing) As MvcHtmlString
        Dim inputName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)
        Dim inputValue = selectedValue 
        //Something like this possible? 
        //inputValue = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionValue(expression)
        Return DatePicker(htmlHelper, inputName, inputValue)
    End Function
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to get the value of the corresponding property that the expression is pointing to you could use the [FromLambdaExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428393.aspx) method:

```
Dim metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression)
Dim value = metadata.Model
```

Comment: In MVC3 ModelMetaData now seems to requires a ViewData parameter, so try: ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

Comment: I used  this :   expression.Compile().Invoke(html.ViewData.Model);  to get value and works fine